# Aligning Content with Bootstrap Navbar on Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a very simple navbar on my page. I'm having trouble aligning content on the right of the navbar on mobile devices. I'm not trying to do any kind of collapsing or anything, I really just want the mobile navbar to look just like the desktop version.

My problem is on mobile devices, my right-aligned content is appearing beneath my header like so:

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW4FH.png)

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9364K.png)

How I have it on Desktop right now is how I pretty much want it. I'd like to vertically align the buttons in the navbar too but I can take care of that part:

Here's my code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Favorite List</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button></li>
        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Try putting `style="display:inline-block"` in the outer most `div`

Comment: Didn't work. Just ended up aligning the buttons next to the navbar-header in the desktop version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fixed this.

use this css in your responsive for mobile view:

```
.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container>.navbar-header {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```